# Как преобразовать тип long в char?

Tags: c++

Как присвоить значение `long` переменной `char`? Я хочу остаток от деления какого-то `num` типа `long` присвоить переменной `s` типа `сhar`:

```
char* ltoao(long num, char s[]) {
    int j;
    while (num > 0) {
        s = num % 8;
        cout << s << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: `s[]` это массив char-ов. Присваивайте, например, первому элементу. `s[0] = num % 8;` / На самом деле, конечно, вам надо написать хотя бы как-то так (**сами подумайте**, как правильно получить **все** восьмеричные цифры) `int j = 0; while(num > 0) { s[j++] = num % 8; num /= 8;}`

Comment: Так , как вы предложили у меня выходит такая ошибка:Вызвано исключение: нарушение доступа для записи.
**s** было 0xCCCCCCCC.

Comment: В **вашей** постановке задачи такой перевод не нужен, выводите просто число. Поэтому дайте точно ваше задание. И еще - в вашем коде бесконечный цикл; так и должно быть?

Comment: Разумеется будет исключение, связанное с переполнением. Вы ведь не передаете в метод `ltoao` размер массива `s` , и соответственно не учитываете этот размер при заполнении массива  значениями.

Comment: @АртёмАлексеев Если вам помог мой ответ, то пожалуйста выберите его как "Правильный ответ" нажав на галочку слева от ответа :) Если же я что-то упустил или есть вопросы, то отпишите в комментарии к ответу и я постараюсь помочь

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Ваша функция должна возвращать `char*`, но вы ничего не возвращаете.
2. Функция `ltoao` не знает о размере `s`, нужно 3 параметром передавать длину строки `s`
3. `int j` вообще нигде не используется
4. У вас `s` в функции, это указатель на первый символ массива и вы пытаетесь на строчке `s = num % 8` присвоить указателю `char*` значение `long`
5. Вы ничего не делаете с `num` и по этому если передать `num > 0`, то вы получите бесконечный цикл.
6. Не понятно зачем в самой функции производить вывод строки `s`.
7. Даже если вы напишите что-то типа такого `s[j] = num % 8` у вас `s[j]` будет символом по таблице `ascii` с кодом `num % 8`, цифры же начинаются с `48`. Так что нужно писать `s[j] = '0' + num % 8; //Или 48 + num % 8`

Вот простой пример кода:

```
//Функция ltoao
//Принимает:
//num - параметр типа long, который должен быть > 0
//Случаи когда num < 0 и num == 0 я не стал рассматривать
//s - указатель на начало строки в которую будет записано спарсенное число
//len - длина строки s
//Возвращает: указатель на строку если все прошло успсешно, иначе nullptr
char* ltoao(long num, char* s, int len) {
    int j = 0;
    //Если длина строки = 0, возвращаем ошибку
    if (len == 0) return nullptr;
    //Пока число num > 0 и мы не дошли до конца строки
    while (num > 0 && j < len) {
        //Заносим остаток от деления на 8 в строку
        //преобразовывая его в символ цифры
        s[j++] = '0' + (num % 8);
        //Делим num на 8 переходя к следующему разряду
        num /= 8;
    }
    //Если мы дошли до конца строки, то возвращаем ошибку
    //т.к. нет места для \0
    if (j == len) return nullptr;
    //Обрезаем строку
    s[j] = '\0';
    //Переворачиваем строку т.к. мы парсим число с конца
    _strrev(s);
    return s;
}
```

Остальные модификации, по типу случая `num < 0` или случай `num = 0`, если нужно, то я думаю у вас не составит труда добавить их.

Answer (score 4):

А вот немного "хакерский" вариант кода для печати восьмеричных чисел.

Идея состоит в том, что в функцию передается **указатель на конец буфера** достаточного размера. Например, для получения восьмеричного представления 64-битного числа достаточно 23 байт (максимум 22 цифры (на каждую 3 бита) и терминирующий строку '\0').

Функция преобразования **заполняет его справа-налево** (т.е. от старших адресов к младшим) и возвращает указатель на старшую цифру.

Т.о. в отличии от традиционных вариантов, результирующую строку перед возвратом из функции **переворачивать не надо**.

```
#include <stdio.h>

static char *
l_to_octstr (unsigned long num, char *s)
{
  *s = 0;

  do {
    *--s = '0' + (num & 7);
  } while (num >>= 3);

  return s;
}

int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  long num;
  char s[24];
  
  while (scanf("%ld", &num) == 1) 
    puts(l_to_octstr(num, s + 23));
  
  return puts("End") == EOF;
}
```

Обратите внимание, что параметр функции д.б. **unsigned** типом.

P.S.
если что-то в коде не понятно, спрашивайте.